# Deploy contract using another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I've seen some example's, where the contract deploys other contract (e.g. [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18936/deploying-contract-from-contract)), but is it possible to do so using binary of the contract? something like:

`function deployContract(bytes contractsBin) { ... }`

As far as I know there is no way to send transaction via contract, so RPC way is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, you just have to rely on solidity assembly to do it.

Check out the create / create2 opcodes:

- **create(v, p, s)** - create new contract with code mem[p..(p+s)) and send v wei and return the new address
- **create2(v, n, p, s)** - create new contract with code mem[p..(p+s)) at address keccak256( . n . keccak256(mem[p..(p+s))) and send v wei and return the new address

You can even go ahead and save gas by "cloning" and existing contract.
An example implementation can be found at: 
https://gist.github.com/holiman/069de8d056a531575d2b786df3345665